# How to get the names of the new columns after performing sklearn Column Transformer

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, one-hot-encoding

```
preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    [
        ('num', StandardScaler(), numeric_features),
        ('cat', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'), categorical_features)
    ]
)
```

I want to perform transformations on both some numeric attributes and also on some categorical features.

Running: `test=preprocessor.fit_transform(X_train)` return a numpy array, which does not have names of columns.

According to documentation the ColumnTransformer should have function get_feature_names(),which would return the names of the new features. However when I run it I get:

```
AttributeError: Transformer num (type StandardScaler) does not provide get_feature_names.
```

I want to get the names of the columns dynamically because I don't know the number of categories in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`ColumnTransformer` takes the column in the same order they are defined in your dataframe, therefore you may consider obtaining them with [pandas select_dtypes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) from your dataframe. Supposing your data is contained in a df:

```
numeric_columns = list(df.select_dtypes('number'))
categorical_columns = list(df.select_dtypes('object')) + list(df.select_dtyes('category'))
```

Comment: My data is originally in a data-frame, however the transformation returns a numpy array and the One hot encoding creates new columns